# No Ubuntu One in Evolution

Tags: ubuntu-one, evolution, contacts

I'm looking to sync my contacts with ubuntu one, and the problem with any instructions on how to do this is that they mention a Ubuntu One -> CouchDB folder under contacts but I see no such thing.

Answer (score 1):

DesktopCouch is installed Via the UbuntuOne application within your Ubuntu desktop.

Open UbuntuOne and, if needed sign in. Once there click on services and at the bottom of the page you will see a link to install the adaption.

Once this is installed two check boxes will appear in its place, one for contacts and one for bookmarks from Firefox.

Tick the box and wait a few minutes (UbuntuOne state 10mins)
Once this is done you should see a new address book called CouchDB in the contact section.

Please bear in mind that the next version of Ubuntu Evolution is being replaced with Thunderbird.